# gcc linking to standard library functions failing

Tags: gcc, gnu-toolchain

undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::_S_copy_chars(char*, char const*, char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21

I am linking my project with standard library(no thirdparty libs in between) i am seeing these kind of errors.When i searched about this error they are saying standard library and my project are build  with different gcc versions. but im linking to std libs part of my toolchain so gcc version should be the same. Any suggestions to find out what exactly is going worng?

I am using -std=c++17 . tried using -std=c++11 too. how to find what version of GLIB used for a library?
GCC compiler version : 10.2.1